# There exist no Fermat numbers which are cubes

Tags: number-theory, fermat-numbers

> Prove that there exist no Fermat numbers which are cubes.

How does one go about proving this? I think the problem is from an olympiad. I've succeeded in proving that no Fermat numbers are squares, but I'm struggling for cubes. An idea I had was to prove that there exists no integer $x$ such that

$$2^{2^n} + 1 = x^3,$$

but I got stuck there. I also saw that there exists a proof for [squares](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat_Number_is_not_Square) on ProofWiki but not for [cubes](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat_Number_is_not_Cube).

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: there is a small integer $m$ such that the cubes modulo $m$ are different from the Fermat numbers modulo $m$.